# Heroku + Backbone.js -- How to check whether in production or development?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, heroku

What is the best way to check if I am running a Backbone.js app on Heroku in production, or locally in development?

For instance, in Node.js, I can check for the presence of `process.env.PORT`, or other environment variables.  However, in backbone `process` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check server-side variables in a client-side app. Your deployment code should take care of setting the configuration for production when you go live. It should do something like:

- update a `release` branch in your git repo with latest changes
- override your config.js file with the values for production

The config can look like:

```
var CONFIG = {
    environment: "production",
    server     : "http://www.example.com"
};
```

Then you can reference the object `CONFIG` around your app.

As a *hack* instead, you could be checking `window.location` to see on which domain you are (localhost, www.example.com etc.)

Comment: So I would have to load a `<script src='config.js'>` for my client backbone app to reference that `CONFIG` var?

Comment: I would put it inside your Backbone app.